# Dynamically refresh JTextPane when a related file changes

Tags: java, swing, refresh, dynamic, jtextpane

The current project in wherein I'm working creates a log file using the `log4j` library and also must have the functionality "showLog" which create a frame where the log can be viewed. Moreover, this frame has to refresh when the log file is modified (appending a new log message).

Well, I have done all except the refresh action, and this is the question, **how can I do the dynamically refresh?**

Here fragments of my code, I put only the relevant lines:

- Interface Action: runs the event actions

  `public interface Action {
      public void executer();
  }`
- Class CadreTexte: Creates and manages the frame wherein the log file is showed

  `public class CadreTexte extends JFrame {
      private JTextPane log;
      public CadreTexte(String titre, File texte) {
          super(titre);
          if (texte.exists() && texte.canRead()) {
              this.texte = texte;
          }
          else {
              throw new ExceptionGenerateurs("NE_FILE"); //Own exception
          }
          initializeFrame();

          log= new JTextPane();
          log.setEditable(false);
          java.net.URL urlFichier = null;
          try {
              urlFichier = texte.toURI().toURL();
          } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
              throw new ExceptionGenerateurs("Fichier de texte non montrable");
          }
          try {
              log.setPage(urlFichier);
          }
          catch (IOException e) {
              System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage()); //CATCH
          } finally {
              urlFichier = null;
          }
          JScrollPane docSP = setScrollPane(); // bars as needed, contains JTextPane
          getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          getContentPane().add(docSP,BorderLayout.CENTER);
      }
  }`
- Class Vue: main frame. It has a list of Action objects which are stored into a HashMap. The actions are accessible throught a menu. Due to this class is very large, I put only the most important lines:

  1. ActionPerformed Function:

     `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     JComponent composant;
     Action handler;
     composant = (JComponent) e.getSource();
     String idEvenement = composant.getName();
     modele.log(Modele.LOG_DEBUG, String.format("Événement. ID: %s",idEvenement));
     handler = ACTIONS_MAP.get(idEvenement);
     if (handler == null) {
         modele.log(Modele.LOG_ERROR, "Action non identifiée");
     } else {
         handler.executer();
         modele.log(Modele.LOG_DEBUG, "Fin action");
     }
     }`
  2. Action visualiserLog:

     `Action visualiserLog = new Action() {
     public void executer() {
         if (cadreLog == null) {
             cadreLog = new CadreTexte("Fichier du log", model.getLogFile());
             visuLog = true;
         }
         else {
             visuLog = !visuLog;
         }
         cadreLog.visualiser(visuLog);
     }
     };`

Finally, the MenuItem which activates the visualiserLog Action it's a `JCheckBoxMenuItem`

I hope you can help me after understand this large question. If someone needs more information, ask for it!

Regards!

NOTE: I'd be very grateful if someone can edit and give correct format to the question, I have been fighting with the editor and it wins me =(

Comment: are you always created a new JFrame on the Runtime for showing file contents in the JTextPane

Comment: No. Only the firt time. If you see the executer function, the frame is created only if it's null, and it is only null when the app starts. After that moment the code shows or hides it, nothing more.

Comment: well, then follows suggestion by @JB Nizet +1 , every actions from `long running threads` or `BackGroung Tasks` must be wrapped into `invokeLater()`, meaning `log.setPage(urlFichier);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that automatic refreshes are a good idea: log files are normally very frequently modified, and can quickly become quite long, so you have a risk of constantly rereading a long file to update the area, and this area, being constantly updated, could become hard to read.

If you really want to do that, I think the only solution is to read the file first and store its length or modification date, and then start a thread which, every N seconds, compares the length or modification date with the one stored in memory.If it has changed, re-read the file and update the text area and the length or modification date.

Be careful not to update the text area from the polling thread, but from the event dispatch thread. Use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to do it.

Comment: Finally I decide to fix the problem with a solution based in your answer. Due that only my app logs in that file, I go to refresh the frame when I write a new log message. In this way I avoid the polling. Thanks for all!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom log4j appender. Your custom appender could somehow notify your GUI that something had been logged - this should be far more efficient than polling a file.

You might be reinventing the wheel though. [Apache Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) looks like it might provide the functionality you require.

Comment: It's not possible configure an appender due to the logger class is a wrapper which can't be extended. This thing is because technically the app doesn't know that the logger is log4j, and although the logger library changes, the app code is not changed, only the logger class.